# How to Add Check Box in Datagrid WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, checkbox

Hi i want to add check box in datagrid view.i have writen test code but fails.
What i am trying to do is Add a CheckBox in datagrid with the items i add into it
with select all and select none option.

I donot know how to do it so i need some help.I am confused with a thing that if we add then dynamically how would we track which checkbox was checked or un checked.

I have current code

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        List<checkedBoxIte> item = new List<checkedBoxIte>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                checkedBoxIte ite = new checkedBoxIte();
                ite.sr = i.ToString();
                ite.ch = new CheckBox();
                item.Add(ite);
            }
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = item
        }
    }
    public class checkedBoxIte
    {
       public string sr {get;set;}
       public CheckBox ch { get; set; }
    }
```

but i know it is stupidest thing to add checkbox like this but it was just a try
Above class contains two attributes later on it would have more but all will be strings

Answer (score 23, accepted):

WPF doesn't know how to deal with your `checkedBoxIte` items. I suggest you to change your class as follows:

```
public class checkedBoxIte
{
   public string MyString {get;set;}
   public bool MyBool { get; set; }
}
```

And then to set the columns of your `DataGrid` in this way:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyString" Binding="{Binding MyString}" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="MyBool" Binding="{Binding MyBool}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Now you can set the `ItemsSource`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    checkedBoxIte ite = new checkedBoxIte();
    ite.MyString = i.ToString();
    item.Add(ite);
}
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = item;
```

Comment: Its working perfectly ok but i have some issues like that first of all there are 4 colums appearing mean repeats2.How can we fire event or check which checkbox is this?

Comment: Well, I don't think that is normal that there are four columns. Are you sure you have set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `False`?

Comment: it was true.Working now.and what can i do for the second part detect checked row

Comment: Attach an handler to `DataGridCellEditEnding` and then extract the row from `Row` property of the `EventArgs`. Alternatively you could implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your class and then see when a `CheckBox` is checked directly from there.