# How would I add Checbox dynamically into a Grid in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql, checkbox, grid

I would like to add some `Checkbox` in a `Grid` control dynamically when the window is loaded in my C# Desktop application. How many times the checkbox will appear depends on the number of entries in a table. Here, I used `LINQ To SQL` class.
The Grid control is defined in XAML.

```
...
<Grid Name="grid1">
   <!-- here i would like to show all check box -->
</Grid>
...
```

Code behind file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
// class declaration ...
...
private void course_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Course> courses = ldc.Courses.ToList();
        foreach (var c in courses)
        {
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
            cb.Name=c.CourseID.ToString();
            cb.Content = c.CourseID.ToString();
            //grid1.Controls.Add(cb); does not work. what to do here?
        }
    }
```

This code is not working. Any suggession?
Thankyou.

Comment: take a look at this maybe it solves your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224181/how-to-add-check-box-in-datagrid-wpf-c-sharp

Comment: how does your binding within the grid look like?

Comment: if you're adding multiple courses you'll need to add multiple grid rows too, just use ListView instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest adding these CheckBoxes to a StackPanel and then add the StackPanel to the grid:

```
StackPanel innerStack;

private void course_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    innerStack= new StackPanel 
    {
        Orientation=Orientation.Vertical
    };
    List<Course> courses = ldc.Courses.ToList();

    foreach (var c in courses)
    {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
        cb.Name = c.CourseID.ToString();
        cb.Content = c.CourseID.ToString();
        innerStack.Children.Add(cb);
    }
    Grid.SetColumn(innerStack,  /*Set the column of your stackPanel, default is 0*/);
    Grid.SetRow(innerStack,  /*Set the row of your stackPanel, default is 0*/);
    Grid.SetColumnSpan(innerStack,  /*Set the columnSpan of your stackPanel, default is 1*/);
    Grid.SetRowSpan(innerStack,  /*Set the rowSpan of your stackPanel, default is 1*/);

    Grid.Children.Add(innerStack);
}
```

If you do not want this structure, you should add some RowDefinition to your grid and use Grid.SetRow(cb, int) method to put ComboBoxes over each other.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong.

First to say you can do grid1.Children.Add(cb);

Then the real issue is that you're using a grid to display a list. There's a very nice ListView for that in WPF with completely style-able rows that can include checkboxes and pretty much everything else you can imagine.

I don't know what your data looks like so I couldn't expand much on the ListView but something like

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Courses}">
     <ListView.View>
           <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="120">
                      <GridViewColumnHeader>
                            <TextBlock Text="Course Name"/>
                      </GridViewColumnHeader>
                      <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                           <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ...UFigureThisOut}"/>
                           </DataTemplate>
                      </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="120">
                      <GridViewColumnHeader>
                            <TextBlock Text="Take That"/>
                      </GridViewColumnHeader>
                      <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                           <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ...UFigureThisOutToo}"/>
                           </DataTemplate>
                      </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn> 
           </GridView> 
     </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```