# Checkbox with DataGrid WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, wpf-4.0

I am trying to create a DataGrid in WPF 4.0 using MVVM...

Features required -

1. Muti - Select rows using a checkbox (single click)
2. A select all checkbox to check all the checkboxes in the datagrid

Something like this -

[image]

It has been 2 days and i am not able to figure out how to solve the problem effectively..

A working example is what I need now ASAP..

I'll highly appreciate if someone has a working solution to share with me...

N please don't tell me to google this thing because none of the things worked out for me...

**UPDATE -**

1. I am using AutoGeneration of Columns
2. I don't want to add "IsSelected" or any of such property in my MODEL..
3. I am just facing 2 problems -

Firstly, "Select all" Feature i.e. checking all checkboxes on the checkbox click of the one present in the column header...(I am able to select and unselect the datagrid but not able to tick/untick the checkboxes)

Secondly, Multiple selection on mouse click without holding Ctrl Key..

Comment: Which part causes you most problems? Putting `CheckBox` in the header? Making it tick/untick all item boxes?

Comment: First google hit: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224181/how-to-add-check-box-in-datagrid-wpf-c-sharp). Dude, seriously. I tend to provide full working samples here in Stackoverflow, but your lack of interest is so evident that I'm not going to answer this.

Comment: HighCore - this i could have achieved in 5 mins without googling the shit!
1. I am using AutoGeneration of Columns
2. I don't want to add "IsSelected" or any of such property in my MODEL..
3. I am just facing 2 problems Firstly, "Select all" Feature i.e. checking all checkboxes on the checkbox click of the one present in the column header... Secondly, Multiple selection on mouse click without holding Ctrl Key..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you're working with MVVM, you have to be aware of what is considered data and what is strictly UI.

Is your `SelectedItems` going to be part of your data, or only your UI?

If it's part of your data, you really should have an `IsSelected` property on your data model, even if that means extending the data class to include an `IsSelected` property, or creating a wrapper class that only contains `bool IsSelected` and `object MyDataItem`. The first option is probably preferred, since you could keep `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`, and it makes the column bindings simpler.

Then you would just bind your `DataGridRow.SelectedItem` to the `IsSelected` property of the data item:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
</Style>
```

But if your `SelectedItems` is only for the UI, or if you are breaking the MVVM pattern for some reason in this instance, than you can create the unbound `CheckBox` and use some code behind to ensure the `CheckBox` is correctly synchronized to the `SelectedItem`.

I did a quick sample app, and here is what my code looked like:

First off, I just added the unbound `CheckBox` column to the column list using a `DataGridTemplateColumn`. This will get added before the `AutoGenerateColumns` list of columns.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="TestDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Test}" 
          SelectionMode="Extended" CanUserAddRows="False"
          PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="TestDataGrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown_1">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="TestCheckBox"
                              PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="CheckBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Second, I added a `PreviewMouseDown` event to the `CheckBox` to make it set the `IsSelected` property of the row.

```cs
private void CheckBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var chk = (CheckBox)sender;
    var row = VisualTreeHelpers.FindAncestor<DataGridRow>(chk);
    var newValue = !chk.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault();

    row.IsSelected = newValue;
    chk.IsChecked = newValue;

    // Mark event as handled so that the default 
    // DataGridPreviewMouseDown doesn't handle the event
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

It needs to navigate the `VisualTree` to find the `DataGridRow` associated with the clicked `CheckBox` to select it, and to make life easier I am using some custom [VisualTreeHelpers that I have on my blog](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/navigating-wpfs-visual-tree/) to find the `DataGridRow`. You can use the same code, or you can create your own method for searching the `VisualTree`.

And last of all, if the user clicks on anywhere other than the `CheckBox`, we want to disable the default `DataGrid` selection event. This ensures that the `IsSelected` value will only change when you click on the `CheckBox`.

There are multiple ways of doing this that will disable the selection at different levels, but to make life simple I just disabled the `DataGrid.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event if the user didn't click on the `CheckBox`.

```cs
private void TestDataGrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var chk = VisualTreeHelpers.FindAncestor<CheckBox>((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource, "TestCheckBox");

    if (chk == null)
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

I using my custom [VisualTreeHelpers](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/navigating-wpfs-visual-tree/) again to navigate the visual tree and find out if the CheckBox was clicked on, and cancelling the event if the user clicked on anywhere other than the `CheckBox`.

As for your 2nd request of adding a `CheckBox` to `SelectAll` or `UnselectAll` items, this would once again be dependent on if your selection is part of the UI or the data.

If it's part of the UI, simply add a `CheckBox` to the `DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate`, and when it's clicked, loop through the `DataGrid.Rows`, find the `CheckBox` in the first column, and check or uncheck it.

If it's part of the data you could still do the same thing (only set the bound value in the `DataGrid.Items` instead of the `CheckBox.IsChecked` from the `DataGrid.Rows`), or you could do as [Adolfo Perez suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17115633/302677), and bind it to a property on the `ViewModel`.

Comment: awesome rachel.. really awesome..            tweaked d code a bit to optimize d working... else it was really neat...

Comment: I have been struggling with this for quite a while, as we create our DataGridTemplateColumns programatically.   Finally, your impl of PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown handler seems to work, attached to the CheckBox like this:  
`checkBoxFactory.AddHandler(PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(ChkBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown));`

Answer (score 4):

For an MVVM Solution you could try this:

```
    <StackPanel>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TestItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="MyDataGrid"
              CanUserAddRows="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Width="50" >
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:Name="dtAllChkBx">
                        <CheckBox Name="cbxAll" Content="All" IsChecked="{Binding Path=DataContext.AllSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

In your `ViewModel`:

```
private void PopulateTestItems()
        {
            TestItems = new ObservableCollection<TestItem>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                TestItem ti = new TestItem();
                ti.Name = "TestItem" + i;
                ti.IsSelected = true;
                TestItems.Add(ti);
            }
        }

        private bool _AllSelected;
        public bool AllSelected
        {
            get { return _AllSelected; }
            set
            {
                _AllSelected = value;
                TestItems.ToList().ForEach(x => x.IsSelected = value);
                NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.AllSelected);
            }
        }

    private ObservableCollection<TestItem> _TestItems;
    public ObservableCollection<TestItem> TestItems
    {
        get { return _TestItems; }
        set
        {
            _TestItems = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.TestItems);
        }
    }
```

And finally the sample Model class:

```
public class TestItem : ModelBase<TestItem>
{
    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.Name);
        }
    }
    private bool _IsSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _IsSelected; }
        set
        {
            _IsSelected = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.IsSelected);
        }
    }
}
```

Most of the code above should be self-explanatory but if you have any question let me know

Answer (score 2):

Your view can be something like

```
    <DataGrid Name="SomeDataGrid" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SomeCollection}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
            Path=DataContext.AllItemsAreChecked}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SomeType}">
                            <CheckBox Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="RandomNumber" Width="160">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SomeType}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=RandomNumber}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Date" Width="160">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SomeType}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Date}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Time" Width="50">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SomeType}">


                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>


                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>                    

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

And in viewmodel 
SomeCollection binding property is an observablecollection
sometype contains properties like IsSelected , RandomNumber ,Date , Time

for eg:

```
    class ViewModel
    {
      public ObservableCollection<SomeType> SomeCollection{get;set;}
    }

    class SomeType
    {
       public string Date {get;set;}
       public string Time {get;set;}
       public string RandomNumber {get;set;}
       public bool IsSelected {get;set;}
    }
```