# Adding checkboxes into data grid C#

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid

I'm trying to add 3 columns of checkboxes in my data grid.

First, with method I put some string values in two columns and after that I want to add 3 more columns of checkboxes.

I found this solution in other post like this one:

```
DataGridCheckBoxColumn chbcolumn = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
for (int j = 0; j == 3; j++)
{
     tabela.Columns.Add(chbcolumn);
}
```

(tabela is the name of the data grid defined in XAML like this):

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="206" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,265,0,0" Name="tabela" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="556" SelectionChanged="tabela_SelectionChanged" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
```

Now this works good for adding one column, but I need two more. I've tried putting that code in for loop, but then I don't get nothing, so obliviously that was a stupid idea. I've tried some other properties of Columns too, but didn't manege to find one that works in this case.

Also, do you maybe know a way to access the name of Columns and changing them? Cause I need 3 different names for those columns.

Does anyone maybe knows some easy way to solve this?

Update:

I make it this way, maybe not the perfect solution, but it did a job.

```
DataGridCheckBoxColumn chbcolumn1 = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
DataGridCheckBoxColumn chbcolumn2 = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
DataGridCheckBoxColumn chbcolumn3 = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
chbcolumn1.Header = "Controller";
chbcolumn2.Header = "Area";
chbcolumn3.Header = "Service";
tabela.Columns.Add(chbcolumn1);
tabela.Columns.Add(chbcolumn2);
tabela.Columns.Add(chbcolumn3);
```

Comment: They should be added when you adding them in loop.

Comment: @ethicallogics hmmm maybe I'm doing it wrong way. I've change the post, adding for loop like I did the first time. Do you maybe see something that's not well defined?

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754608/what-is-the-code-behind-for-datagridtemplatecolumn-and-how-to-use-it

Comment: Check this...
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5224523/3156647

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using code behind, try it with XAML. A simple checkbox column can be defined like this

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
      <DataGrid.Columns>            
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="TextColumn1" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="TextColumn1" Binding="{Binding LastName}" />
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="TextColumn1" Binding="{Binding Address}" />

       <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="CheckBoxColumn1">
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsActive}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn>

       <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="CheckBoxColumn2">
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsAlive}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn>

       <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="CheckBoxColumn3">
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsParticipating}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the same instance Column in a loop. Try this

```
for (int j = 0; j == 3; j++)
{
 DataGridCheckBoxColumn chbcolumn = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
 tabela.Columns.Add(chbcolumn);
 }
```

Comment: I've tried that way the first time, but it was the same. Anyway I've managed to fix it in the other way. I made 3 different instance of DataGridCheckBoxColumn... It's not maybe the best solution, but it will work for now :)